# How to correct using relationships with :foreign_key between two models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

```
class User 
   has_many :disputes
end

class Dispute
    belongs_to :claimant, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => :claimant_id
    belongs_to :indicted, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => :indicted_id
end
```

I want to ask about relationships.

@dispute.claimant.name and @dispute.indicted.name work good, but how could I use reverse-relation, mean @claimant.dispute.reason for example. I think I can use `@indicted_disputes = Dispute.select {|x| x.indicted_id == current_user.id}`, but I don't have any idea how fast this works with huge database.

I try to create some methods in disputes_controller: sent_disputes (all user disputes where user.id == claimant_id) and received_disputes (where user.id == indicted_id).
But don't understand how to setup user like claimant? Usual way to setup user is @user = User.find(params[:user_id]), I want build something similar: @claimant = User.find(params[:claimant_id]) and after do @claimant.disputes (where shall be only disputes where user is a claimant) 
Is the other more "natural" way to use "claimant-relationship" and load some data like @claimant.dispute.reason?
Appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.disputes.where (claimant_id: @user.id)
@user.disputes.where (indicted_id: @user.id)
```

Because of the `has_many` relationship a user can be claimant and indicted for multiple disputes at the same time. If you just want to check if a user is a claimant:

```
@user.disputes.where(claimant_id: @user.id).present?
```

Comment: I have an error when I try to apply your solution.


`def disputes_list
    @disputes = current_user.disputes.where(:indicted_id == current_user.id)
    @disputes = @disputes.paginate(page: params[:page]) if @disputes.any?
end`

return an error
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: disputes.user_id: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "disputes" WHERE "disputes"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1